# Sqoop: using octal value(\0) as delimiter

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Since I have special char in one of the fields, I wanted to use lower value as delimiter. Hive works fine with the delimiter(\0) but sqoop fails with NoSuchElement Exception. Looks like it is not detecting the delimiter as \0.

This is how my hive an sqoop script looks like. Any help please.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.test
(
    name CHAR(20),
    id    int,
    dte_report date
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\0' 
LOCATION '/user/$USER/test';

sqoop-export \
    -Dmapred.job.name="TEST" \
    -Dorg.apache.sqoop.export.text.dump_data_on_error=true \
    --options-file ${OPTION_FILE_LOCATION}\conn_mysql \
    --export-dir /user/$USER/test \
    --input-fields-terminated-by '\0' \
    --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
    --input-null-string '\\N' \
    --input-null-non-string '\\N' \
    --table MYSQL_TEST \
    --validate \
    --outdir /export/home/$USER/javalib
```

In VI editor, the delimiter looks like '^@' and with od -c the delimiter is \0

Comment: Looks like a typo for me, your input fields in sqoop parameter is set to zero not “o”

Answer (score 0):

You should use \000 as delimiter , it will generate that character as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Set the character set to UTF 8 in the my sql conn string that can resolve this issue.

```
mysql.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nbs?useJvmCharsetConverters=false&useDynamicCharsetInfo=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8&useEncoding=true
```